# Choosing length of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, plot, netcdf

If I have a NumPy array of type float in Python, how can I choose some values from my array? I have `z = [0.1, ... 40, 41.5, 42, ..., 60]` and I want to use just `z = [40, 41.5, 42, ..., 60]`?

I thought I could use this:

```
z=data.variables['something'][40:]
a=np.interp(0,x,z)
ValueError: fp and xp are not of the same length
```

But an error occurred.

I am plotting a graph and I need to find some values of `x` corresponding to the y axis (where `z` lies), but not from the beginning of the y axis. While plotting I used `xlim` and `ylim` but this is used after calling the plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that in your example, you want to take the values above 40, try doing it like this:

```
z=data.variables['something']
index = z >= 40
a=np.interp(0,x[index],z[index])
```

The way you were doing it before would only skip the first 40 entries in `z`. That's python indexing for ya.